# Essence of relations between central simple algebras and Galois cohomology in canonical morphism of class field theory

Tags: class-field-theory, galois-cohomology, central-simple-algebras

I was somewhat puzzled after I finished learning class field theory for several times. My question is about the relations between "classical simple algebras, Brauer groups" and "modern cohomology theory". (If this question is naive to experts, I apologize sincerely.)

The formalism of class field theory before the introduction of the cohomological formalism is very explicit as follows (My favourite reference is Weil's Basic number theory): The canonical morphism is constructed by cyclic algebras. If $K$ is a local field, then the "pairing" $X_K\times K^*\rightarrow \mathbb{C}^1$ between the character group $X_K$ of $Gal(K^{ab}/K)$ and $K^*$ is given by the following well-known process. First we have to know the Brauer group $B(K)=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ (identified with the group of all roots of unity in $\mathbb{C}^1$), then given $\chi\in X_K$ and $a\in K^*$, $ker(\chi)$ determines a cyclic extension $K'/K$, we can define the pairing to be the class of cyclic algebra $[K'/K,a]:=[K,\chi,a]\in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{C}^1$.

After this explicit construction, we got a map ("canonical morphism") from $K^*$ to the Pontryagin dual of $X_K$, which is exactly $Gal(K^{ab}/K)$ by Pontryagin duality. And in the global context we glue the local data via ideles, and the key point is Hasse's reciprocity, which claims it factors through the ideles class group $\mathbb{I}_K/K^*$.

O.K. That's the "classical" roadmap based on the theory of central simple algebras. In "modern" roadmap of Galois cohomology, one first establish a series of axioms (following Artin-Tate) for a general profinite group $G$ and a continuous $G$-module $A$, coming from this model: namely a series of routine functorical properties (a "formation") and two key points:

(1) Hilbert's satz 90: vanishing of $H^1$ (a "field formation");

(2) A functorial isomorphism of $H^2$ with $\cup_{n\geq 1} \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}=\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ (a "class formation").

Then you can start with the huge and powerful machinery of (Tate's) cohomology to obtain Tate's theorem: the cup product map $H^q(G, \mathbb{Z})\rightarrow H^{q+2}(G,A)$ is a functorial isomorphism, which provides the canonical morphism of CFT at $q=-2$: $H^{-2}(G, \mathbb{Z})=G^{ab}$, $H^{0}(G,A)=A^G/N_G A.$ In the local case you take $A=K^*$, and in the global case you first take $A=\mathbb{I}_K$ and then $\mathbb{I}_K/K^*$.

I learnt cohomological aspects from Neukirch's excellent book "Class Field Theory, Bonn Lectures". It's very beautiful and carefully written. I spent much time checking each step and details. I was very striking that this somewhat abstract machinery DOES package the "classical" version.

But so far, I still couldn't get an intuitive explanation: how did this machinery correspond to the classical version? For example, in the "classical" version you get this canonical morphism from the Brauer group very directly, which should correspond to $H^2$ in cohomology. But in the "modern" version you get the cup product morphism from $H^{-2}$ and $H^{0}$. This looks very different. So you must have already done "something" from the class formation axiom for $H^2$ and cohomological machinery to get this. Just as Neukirch wrote on his book (page 78):"Before the introduction of cohomology theory, algebras were used to describe local class field theory; we remark that the use of cohomology has led to considerable simplifications." What makes me puzzled is exactly "how this modern machinery correspond to operations in the classical context".

Comment: I should explain my background: Indeed I'm a student learning automorphic representations. My professor told me for people studying automorphic forms, Weil's book Basic Number Theory is of fundamental importance, because it's indeed a book on "how CFT=GL(1) automorphic representations". Obviously it inculded too many things only necessary for automorphic representations: such as Eichler's theorem on norm of simple algebras over number fields, proved by considering zeta (automorphic $L$-) functions; structure of simple algebras (indeed he is dealing with inner forms of $GL(n)$).

Comment: You write ${\rm Gal}(F^{ab}/F)$ multiple times but there is no field $F$ elsewhere.

Comment: Are you asking how mathematicians recognized that the formalism of class field theory involving Brauer groups could be expressed in terms of group cohomology, as a stepping stone to the purely cohomological formulation of class field theory?

Comment: @KConrad Oh thanks a lot for that typo. OK, I think in some sense that's exactly what made me puzzled. But to be more concrete, I just want to "see": intuitively, the reciprocity maps obtained in these 2 formalisms really coincide!

Comment: The reciprocity map is far enough along in the development that I am suspicious about seeing why it coincides in two formalisms "intuitively".  For the simplest instance, consider quadratic extensions.  Have you ever worked out why the Hilbert reciprocity law over $\mathbf Q$ is equivalent to the quadratic reciprocity law for the Legendre symbol?

Comment: @KConrad  Oh my god, you are right. That’s the simplest nontrivial example of the 2 formalisms. I first read the equivalence of these 2 versions on Kato-Kurihara-Saito’s book (AMS translated version) Number theory 1–Fermat’s dream (Kato is a master), they gave very detailed computation in section 2.3 on the equivalence of Hilbert’s local quadratic symbol and global quadratic reciprocity over $\mathbb{Q}$! And in section 8.2 they explained why local quadratic Hilbert symbol corresponds accurately to the ramifications of quaternions. Thanks, Keith! I didn’t realize these before!

Comment: @KConrad But logically the general equivalence of the two formalisms still looks very delicate. I remembered that Tate wrote in Cassels-Frohlich somewhere that Artin’s reciprocity is right because “that’s the only possibility”.

Comment: Sure, the general equivalence is delicate. But that does not seem to be what you were asking about.

Comment: @KConrad ok. Is there any literature/references dealing with this? I guess this must be implicitly contained in many books. But it’s far from clear for me.

Comment: I do not think it is implicitly (or explicitly) contained in many books. Developing class field theory just by one approach is a long slog on its own, so an author typically picks *one* approach, not two. Someone who chooses to write up CFT using group cohomology or central simple algebras is unlikely to show how it matches up with CFT using the other method because the treatment has not developed CFT using both methods.

Comment: It is like asking why classical power reciprocity laws are implied by the Artin reciprocity law (justifying the name “reciprocity law”). I’ve seen a few accounts do this for the quadratic reciprocity law over $\mathbf Q$, but I don’t know a book where this is done for the cubic reciprocity law over $\mathbf Q(\omega)$ or the biquadratic reciprocity law over $\mathbf Q(i)$.  (Maybe Lemmermeyer’s book?) For cubic reciprocity, Noah Snyder wrote up an explanation in his senior thesis, but there was a gap. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234358/artin-reciprocity-implies-cubic-reciprocity.

Comment: Section 14.2 of Pierce’s *Associative Algebras* explains why, for a finite Galois extension $E/F$, the subgroup of elements of the Brauer group of $F$ that are split when base extended to $E$ is isomorphic to a second Galois cohomology group. The point is that the structure coefficients used to define the multiplication of a basis in a crossed product algebra are a 2-cocycle. This was the clue that one might be able to discard all the simple algebras in CFT by using only group cohomology.

Comment: At the start of Part Two of Lang’s *Algebraic Number Theory*, he spends a few pages describing how class field theory went through various approaches. According to that, the person who first suggested building up CFT purely through group cohomology was Hochschild in 1950.

Comment: @KConrad Thanks a lot. Neukirch's book (Bonn lectures on CFT) explained how cohomological tools can be used to deduce Hasse's reciprocity ( page 145-146), and also he expained how the cohomological theorems implies the classical Artin reciprocity ( ideal theoretic, Frobenius-Artin symbol). But I didn't think it really resolved my question.  Your comments are very helpful. :)

Comment: @KConrad In some sense, it looks like cohomology only provides a small amount of information hidden in simple algebras? For example, it can't provide more information about representations of multiplicative groups ( over local fields) of simple algebras, which is a fundamental problem in the theory of automorphic forms. Cohomological tools 'ignores' some information in simple algebras.

Comment: Each finite-dimensional central simple algebra over a global or local field is a crossed product algebra, and in fact is a cyclic algebra. In a crossed product algebra the addition is componentwise for a basis indexed by the Galois group and the multiplicative relations among that basis are determined by the structure constants, which form a 2-cocycle. So the operations defining that simple algebra are completely determined by a 2-cocycle. That is why CFT was able (after hard work) to be expressible in terms of cohomology.  At this point, maybe talk in person with faculty in your department.